# Simplifying large symbolic expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I am working on creating a function that does the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of an equation using sympy. I am trying to get the code to simplify the expression, but the simplification function won't work (I assume because of the size of the expression). This is for a general Legendre transformation, so I can't tell it to look for specific simplification.

As and example one output equation has the trig relation:
sin^2 = 1 - cos^2

To set up the problem

```
import sympy as sy
x, y, m1, m2, n, q1, q2, tht = sy.symbols("x, y, m1, m2, n, q1, q2, tht")
```

When I code that and use trigsimp()

```
a = x - x*sy.cos(tht)**2
print(sy.trigsimp(a))
```

I get

```
x*sin(tht)**2
```

like I should. However, when I put it into a more complex problem.

```
b = y*n**2/(x**2*y**2*(-m1 - m2*sy.cos(q1 - q2)**2 + m2))
print(sy.trigsimp(b))
```

I doesn't recognize the trig relationship and outputs:

```
n**2/(x**2*y*(-m1 - m2*cos(q1 - q2)**2 + m2))
```

Is there any way to simplify a large expression, or is there something betting than sympy I could use for this application?

edit:

To clarify the problem, a moderate amount of complexity seems to stump trigsimp(), shown by example b not being simplified properly. I am looking for a way to have a more rigorous simplification of the equation. For scale, the functions that I really want to simplify are 3-20 times larger than example b.

Comment: There isn't a clear similarity between equations `a` and `b`, hence the output will not be similar either. You do realize that `b` does not have the shape of `a`?

Comment: I meant form. The `a` part clearly works. However, the `b` has nothing to do with `a`, so why mention it? Furthermore, if the function returns a different output from `b`, then it already worked for `b` unless you made a typo in the `b` output? is there a `y*` missing in the last equation?

Comment: What do you mean by different shape?

a = x - x*sy.cos(tht)^2 -> a = x*(1 - cos(tht)^2 -> a = x*sin(tht)^2

part_of_b = -m1 - m2*cos(q1 - q2)^2 + m2 -> -m1 + m2*(1 -  cos(q1 - q2)^2) -> m1 + m2*sin(q1 - q2)^2

They are different, but the trig simplification should still act the same. Did I make a mistake in my math?

Comment: Essentially I am just saying trigsimp only appears to work on very simple and obvious cases. b is proof that even a bit of complexity stumps the function. The equation that I am trying to simplify is around 20 times longer than b so I have no chance of that being simplified. I was looking for something that could. Also I sent my previous comment prematurely hence why some stuff was missing.

Comment: I get your point. You made a typo in your comment, last part it is -m1, otherwise it looks fine. It is not easy to notice though, so I suggest including it in the question.

Comment: I suggest formulating the question a bit better and consider opening an issue in the sympy project [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with larger expression it is normally better to give more direct instructions for simplification e.g.

```
In [18]: b.replace(cos, lambda a: sqrt(1-sin(a)**2)).collect(m2)                                                                  
Out[18]: 
               2             
              n              
─────────────────────────────
 2   ⎛            2         ⎞
x ⋅y⋅⎝-m₁ + m₂⋅sin (q₁ - q₂)⎠
```

That might not work in your actual problem but something should. The difficulty with generic routines like trigsimp and simplify is that there isn't a universally correct strategy for simplification so they have to try lots of things which is ends up being either slow or incomplete (or both). In fact it's not always clear what the "simplest" answer should be. The improvement in this example seems pretty marginal.